# Get Data From Jsp To Ajax Not Working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

This is not even enter to the server in debug

```
$.ajax({
              type: 'GET',

              url: 'http://192.168.1.12:8080/HelpCenterService/api/db/getPatientsList',
              dataType: 'json',
               success: function (d) {
                   alert("good");
               },
               error: function () {
                   alert("bad");
               }
          });
```

This is enter inside of the server in debug but I am not getting any data to the `var aa`

```
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
        request.open('GET', 'http://192.168.1.12:8080/HelpCenterService/api/db/getPatientsList', true);



        request.send(null);
        var aa = request.responseText;
        alert(aa);
```

If I write the link=http://192.168.1.12:8080/HelpCenterService/api/db/getPatientsList
 into the url of chrome
I get

```
[{"tel":"01111111","address":"abc","birthDate":"11/11/1980","gender":1,"id":1,"firstName":"abc","lastName":"abc"}]
```

This is the jsp server side

```
@Path("/getPatientsList") 
    @GET 
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    public ArrayList<Patient> getPatientsList() throws Exception {

 //  a lot of funcs inside
        return pList; 
    }
```

Comment: In your browser when the request is failing, what is url for the page? Are you using localhost?

Comment: i dont understand, i always use this link http://192.168.1.12:8080/HelpCenterService/api/db/getPatientsList, in the browser i always get the data but in ajax i dont get

Comment: YES I USE using localhost ALL TIME

Comment: I was concerned about the browser enforcing same-origin rule. The browser does not see localhost and 192.168.1.12 as the same and it wont even send it. Try opening up your browser tools by hitting CTRL+SHIFT+J. Look at the network panel, and see if you can find your request.

Comment: You should remove the base url in the ajax. The browser will infer the current URL from `/path/to/get/from`

Answer (score 0):

If you'll open the console i think that you'll recive a messge like "Cross Origin Access Control Error", which means that if the issuer doesn't have a Domain name like the API server, the API server should be configed to publish jsons for the public, aka Cross Oigin Access "*".

you should read about it here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

anyway, if you want to do it localy, you can refer the server as Localhost and then everything will be ok.